# Visual Studio Test has Upload Test Attachments set to false but it uploads attachments regardless

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

The 'Visual Studio Test' task has an option named 'Upload test attachments', regardless of if this option is on or off for a release it is always uploading test attachments.

This is now occurring on two specific build agents in my agent pool and it is a change of behavior from around the end of last week.

There is no known change in release definition.

I have tried creating a new release definition and new and old release definitions exhibit this behavior.

In the past the only way we have stopped this undesired behavior is to recreate the build agents.

Answer (score 0):

The hosted agent now has a set of Watcher plugins, these are enabled by default now. [The watcher looks for specific tasks in the workflow and auto-enables](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/2e77bb210d787082c4fa1999ac4a17d2e1aca601/src/Agent.Plugins/TestFilePublisher/Plugin/TestFilePublisherLogPlugin.cs).

Looking at the code, it will auto-disable when you add a Publish Test Results Task, even if it has a condition that causes it not to run.

Any chance the Agent Version has updated itself?

Comment: Agent.Version is currently 2.155.1 which was released 15 days ago, we haven't updated since that version at the end of July, the change of behavior I am describing is in the last 4 days

Comment: What version of the task is in the agents tasks folder?

Comment: What task version is configured in the pipeline.

Comment: Configured in the pipeline : 2.155.4
On the agent in the tasks folder : 2.155.4

I can see 2 releases of the same definition, one with the desired behavior, one without the desired behavior, in both cases the version of the task configured in the pipeline is  2.155.4